# Getting the Git Long Hash from MSBuild

Tags: git, github, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, msbuild-task

I am using `Git` + `MSBuild`. I need to get the Git Long Hash number from `MSBuild` so that I can tie a build to the hash number (and find out what files made up that "revision")

Is there a built in task in `MSBuild` I can use to get the hash number?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend passing it as property from CI sever itself whose job it is to deal with VCS, that way devs can use the same script against ordinary folder that isn't a git repo, e.g. a dumb copy/paste for hacking around by providing it from CLI. That said, there might be proper api-based community task but I did it with:

```
<Target Name="Foo">
    <Exec Command="git rev-parse HEAD > head" />
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="head">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" PropertyName="Head" /> 
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <Delete Files="head" />
    <Message Text="Head: $(Head)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Bar">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Head>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(".git\refs\heads\master").Trim())</Head>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="Head: $(Head)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `git describe --tags --always --dirty` instead of `git rev-parse`. It produces nicely formatted version numbers, including short SHAs, e.g.: `1.5.0-RC-119-g30d0a09-dirty`